# How to have SQL Inner Join to return first entry or blank if no entry

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

First time posting; been reading alot of answers, and most have helped, but I've gotten stuck on this one.  Using Oracle SQL, I'm trying to perform a select with an inner join, but I want to select the first entry from a another table if there is one.

Abbrieviated example:

```
Table_1
-ID
-Value

1 XYZ
2 ABC
3 DEF

Table_2
-ID
-Value_2

1 Sample_1
3 Sample_2
3 Sample_3
```

And the result of the select, I am trying to get:

```
1 XYZ Sample_1
2 ABC ''
3 DEF Sample_2
```

The select statement I'm using is

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ID,Value,Value_2 FROM Table_1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
WHERE Value_2 = (SELECT MIN(Value_2) FROM Table_2 WHERE ID=Table_2.ID)
);
```

But the result I'm getting is dropping all the rows where Table_2 doesn't have a match.

```
1 XYZ Sample_1
3 DEF Sample_2
```

I tried using COALESCE(), but I'm guessing No Rows Selected isn't the same as NULL.  Wish I could use TOP(), but I cannot.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you want LEFT JOIN rather than INNER JOIN. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a `LEFT JOIN` against a correlated subquery which returns the `MIN(Value_2)` per `ID`. The `LEFT JOIN` is needed to get blanks absent a match.

```
SELECT
  Table_1.ID,
  Table_1.Value,
  minval.Value_2
FROM
  Table_1
  /* Subquery returns least Value_2 per group of ID */
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MIN(Value_2) AS Value_2 FROM Table_2 GROUP BY ID
  ) minval ON Table_1.ID = minval.ID
```

Note, that there really isn't a "first" without an `ORDER BY`. I have chosen the one that sorts first by `Value_2`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30a6c/5

(Sorry for all the edits - couple of bugfixes in the SQLfiddle)

Comment: That did exactly what I was hoping!  Thanks for pointing out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for you?

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT ID,Value,Value_2 FROM Table_1 
 INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
 WHERE Value_2 = (SELECT MIN(Value_2) FROM Table_2 WHERE ID=Table_2.ID)
 Order by ID Desc limit 0,1
 );
```

Comment: Actually, Order by/Limit with Joins will be slow unless you're working with very small data, refer to the above poster.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's solution is of course correct if you need any other information from `Table_2`, or need to join other tables (although you can convert my solution to a subselect to work around that). But just to obtain the specific result requested, you can use this simple query:

```
SELECT Table_1.ID, Table_1.Value, MIN(Table_2.Value_2)
  FROM Table_1
  LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
  GROUP BY Table_1.ID, Table_1.Value
```